# How to re run a failed message in reactive kafka 0.8.2.2

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, akka-stream, reactive

I want to re-publish the messages for x no of times which failed to process. I see the manual commit code:

```
val consumerWithOffsetSink = kafka.consumeWithOffsetSink(consumerProperties)
Source.fromPublisher(consumerWithOffsetSink.publisher)
.map(processMessage(_)) // your message processing
.to(consumerWithOffsetSink.offsetCommitSink) // stream back for commit
.run()
```

However, how to handle exceptions in the processMessage() method? I would like to handle the exception and ask kafka to re run the message 3 times. If it still fails after 3 times, discard it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider defining a dead-letter queue (other storage like DB is also okay) to store these messages, and then, we could attempt to analysis and solve them.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are able to handle read-at-least-once, but you don't want to stop permanently in case of failures and would rather like the process to continue with rest of the messages after 3 retries of the failed message.

This could have been easily achieved using simple consumer in apache kafka. Let me know if that is an option and I would explain that.

In case of reactive kafka, after three re-tries in processMessage, we will have to look at a way of returning what a 'processed' message returns. That way it would include that (offset of the failed message) in the next offset commit into the sink (as if it was processed), and would not come up again.